# Reading and modifying Microsoft Word document using C#

Tags: c#, ms-word

I'm new to C# and I need a little help. I have to load Microsoft word files in richTextBox, modify text, and save that text in some of Microsoft Word formats.
I would appreciate if you could point me to libraries and examples that I should use to achieve this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a newer version of MS Office, you should look into [OpenXML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=C6E744E5-36E9-45F5-8D8C-331DF206E0D0&displaylang=en).  Older versions of Word will require Interop directly to Word.

The benefit to OpneXML SDK is your application will not use Office directly.  You won't need to have Office installed on every machine your app runs.  The downside (depending on how you look at it) is you'll only be able to save the newer OpenXML format (.docx).

Answer (score 3):

Look into `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` namespace.  It should have most of what you need.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word(v=office.11).aspx